# RegExp , Notepad++ Replace / remove several values

Tags: regex

I have this dataset: (about 10k times)

```
<Id>HOW2SING</Id>
<PopularityRank>1</PopularityRank>
<Title><![CDATA[Superior Singing Method - Online Singing Course]]></Title>
<Description><![CDATA[High Quality Vocal Improvement Product With High Conversions.     Online Singing Lessons Course Converts Like Crazy Using Content Packed Sales Video. You Make 75% On Every Sale Including Front End, Recurring, And 1-click Upsells!]]></Description>
<HasRecurringProducts>true</HasRecurringProducts>
<Gravity>45.9395</Gravity>
<PercentPerSale>74.0</PercentPerSale>
<PercentPerRebill>20.0</PercentPerRebill>
<AverageEarningsPerSale>74.9006</AverageEarningsPerSale>
<InitialEarningsPerSale>70.1943</InitialEarningsPerSale>
<TotalRebillAmt>16.1971</TotalRebillAmt>
<Referred>75.0</Referred>
<Commission>75</Commission>
<ActivateDate>2011-06-23</ActivateDate>
</Site>
```

I am trying to do the following:

Get the data from within the  tags, and use it to create a URL, so in this example it should make

http://www.reviews.how2sing.domain.com

also, all other data has to go, i want to perform a REGEX function that will just give me a list of URLS.

I prefer to do it using notepad++ but i suck at regex, any help would be welome

Comment: Thanks for accepting answer. If you are interested, I added the more advanced regex that does it all in one step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the regex relatively simple you can just use:

```
.*?<id>(.+?)</id>
```

Replace with:

```
http://www.reviews.\1.domain.com\n
```

That will search and replace all instances of Id tag and preceding text. You can then just remove the last manually.

[image]

Make sure `matches newline` is selected.

Regex is straightforward, only slightly tricky part is that it uses `+?` and `*?` which are non-greedy. This prevents the whole file from being matched. The `()` indicate a capture group that is used in the replacement, i.e. `\1`.

If you want to a regex that will include replacing the last part then use:

```
.*?(?:(<id>)?(.+?)</id>).+?(?:<id>|\Z)
```

This is a bit more tricky, it uses:

- `?:`. A non-capturing group.
- `|` OR
- `\Z` end of file

Basically, the first time it will match everything up to the end of the first `</id>` and replace up to and including the next `<id>`. After that it will have replaced the starting `<id>` so everything before `</id>` goes in the group. On the last match it will match the end of file `\Z`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the `Id` values, you can do:

`'<Id>([^<]*)<\/Id>'`

Then you can get the first captured group `\1` which is the Id text value and then create a link from it.

Here is a demo:

http://regex101.com/r/jE9qN8

[UPDATE]

To get rid of all other lines, match this regex: `'.*<Id>([^<]*)<\/Id>.*'` and replace by first captured group `\1`. Note for the regex match, since there are multiple lines, you will need to have the `DOTALL` or `/s` flag activated to also match newlines.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this only gets me my id;s and allows me to add them to the link (wich works fine btw!). However, i also want to get rid of all other lines in the file (The non id data)

Comment: @user2015766. Answer updated. If it was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thank you.

Comment: Hello, How would i activate that flag? I checked the Matches newline box, but it still doesnt work, the link gets created just fine, but the rest of the text remains

Comment: @user2015766, In python it is done by `re.DOTALL`, in php as: `/some_regex/s`. I'm sorry I don't know about your case.

Comment: It appears it was the checkbox, it works now but i have this dataset as above 10000 times in one file. Your regex works, but it only matches <id> once, so it gives me 1 link, instead of 10k

Comment: @user2015766. Again, I'm sorry I don't know how to do it in your case but in php you can add the `/g` tag that returns all matches instead of just one.